# Magento : Error Backend Opening Product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, zend-framework

I can not open any product anymore in backend.

After some seconds, Magento error page shows up, with following error report:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:31:"Read timed out after 10 seconds";i:1;s:4472:"#0 /lib/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php(329): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->_checkSocketReadTimeout()
```

What causes this issue and how can I solve this?

I am running Magento CE 1.9.3.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you can simply increase the timeout from 10 seconds to 20 or 30. Whatever is appropriate for you.

Edit the following file on your server: /lib/Zend/Http/Client.php

Locate the following line:
‘timeout’ => ....